# Android database upgrade Issue

Tags: android, sqlite

I  have a application which has Database
now i want to release new version of the applicaton
but my database has new field added 
and i want to keep my old data in database  and also add new database with additional fields

Will my database will be overided(i will losse my copy of data) or new database will be added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

focus on ***onUpgrade*** method :-)

```
public class WIMProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private DatabaseHelper mOpenHelper;

    // ..... code .....

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private Context mContext;

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            if (oldVersion == 1) {
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE TCategory ADD COLUMN fiDefault integer DEFAULT 0");
                oldVersion++;
            }
            if (oldVersion == 2) {
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE TCategory ADD COLUMN fsIcon nvarchar(50)");
                oldVersion++;
            }
        }
}
```